# Failed to use ICMP under wine3.11 (staging)

Tags: networking, permissions, wine

I've tried to install ffxiv on my ubuntu 16.04 via wine3.11. In the game, after choosing data center, system tried to connect to it, but return the error:

IcmpCreateFile Failed to use ICMP (network ping), this requires special permissions.
004c:fixme:winediag:IcmpCreateFile Falling back to system 'ping' command as a workaround.
004c:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {94297043-bd82-4dfd-b0de-8177739c6d20} not registered
004c:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {94297043-bd82-4dfd-b0de-8177739c6d20} not registered
004c:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {94297043-bd82-4dfd-b0de-8177739c6d20} could be created for context 0x3

I've tried to solve it via:

sudo setcap cap_net_raw+epi /usr/bin/wine64-preloader

But it return other error:

Failed to set capabilities on file `/usr/bin/wine64-preloader' (Invalid argument)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file

After that I tried use this method to resolve ping problem:

sudo chmod 4755 /bin/ping

And launch game by this string:

env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/ffxiv2 wine ffxivboot.exe

But it doesn't change anything.

Comment: ...did you try the workarounds on [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=32580)?

Comment: oh, thanks, I missed part about deleting web folder!

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar error when running `wine ping.exe www.google.ca`, what worked for me :

1. Set cap has to be on the file, not on the symlink: `sudo setcap cap_net_raw+epi /opt/wine-stable/bin/wine-preloader`
2. `sudo ln -s /opt/wine-stable/lib/libwine.so.1 /usr/lib/libwine.so.1`

This got `wine ping.exe www.google.ca` to work, but not my install of Among Us :-(